# Implicit Differentiation Step Explanation

Tags: physics, implicit-differentiation

I'm trying to follow some notes on beam mechanics, and there is a differentiation step I don't understand.

He goes from:

$M_n(\lambda(1-R)+R) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{(R-1)(1-\lambda)^2(2+\lambda)}{6}$

to:

$\frac{dM_n}{d\lambda}(\lambda(1-R)+R) + M_n(1-R) = \frac{R-1}{6}(-2(1-\lambda)(2+\lambda)+(1-\lambda)^2)$

I can do the R.H.S, but I don't understand how the L.H.S is differentiated. Also some insights into how the R.H.S is differentiated in one step would be very useful!

Can anyone help me understand this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the lhs as a product of two functions $f(\lambda) = M_n (\lambda)$ and $g(\lambda) = \lambda(1-R) +R$.

Note that $f'(\lambda) = \frac{dM_n}{d\lambda}$, $g'(\lambda) = 1-R$.

Then the derivative wrt $\lambda$ is:

$$f'(\lambda)g(\lambda)+f(\lambda)g'(\lambda)= \frac{dM_n}{d\lambda}(\lambda(1-R) +R)+M_n (\lambda)(1-R).$$

Comment: Ah of course, thank you. It's been a long time since I've done any of this. You've got a slight typo though the `(1+R)` terms should be `(1-R)`

Comment: Any idea how the R.H.S is done in one step, btw?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by one step. It is another application of the product rule applied to $(1-\lambda)^2(2+\lambda)$.

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot, I multiplied out the brackets!. Thank you very much.